# Is it legal to install WIndows 7 Professional (OEM) on VMWare?

Tags: windows, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

I recently heard that Microsoft allow you to install OEM version of windows 7 into Virtual Machine. I'm not 100% sure whether it is true or not and would like to re-confirm with you guys.

FYI, I have 2 computers.  Let's say "computer A" and "Computer B".

I bought a copy of WIndows 7 Professional OEM edition recently and already installed it on my Computer A.
I've two questions:

1. Is it legal to install it again on a VMWare/Virtual PC on my Computer A?
2. Is it legal to install it on VMWare/Virtual PC on my Computer B?

Thanks.

Comment: Adding as a comment since I'm not certain but my understanding is you require one license for every installed copy of Windows.  If you want to install Windows 7 Professional OEM in VMWare Player on a computer running Windows 7 Professional OEM, you would need 2 licenses.

Comment: The way I read it, OP is asking about installing three machines  (possibly four; the question is kind of unclear) from one OEM-licensed copy of Win 7; I don't really see that addressed in the linked question.

Comment: If you are just evaluating the software Microsoft generally doesn't have an issue with more people becoming familiar with their software.  So it depends on what you plan using it for? i.e. Just installing it isn't so much an issue as using it for longer than a trial is necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each installation requires its own license.  A machine running Windows (one license) with VMWare Player hosting a VM running Windows (one more license) needs two licenses.

Of course, IANAL, and you're getting into a grey area as OEM licenses are officially tied to a specific machine once installed, can't be sold or transferred, etc.

Comment: +1 for OEM being "tied" to specific hardware.

Comment: Ack.  I just realized that @Kyle_Smith and I apparently wrote nearly the same thing at nearly the same time.